# error al obtener datos con requests

Tags: python, flask

Hice un web service con `flask` en `python`. y lo llamo desde `php`, pero ahora necesito llamarlo desde `python` y no encontre como hacerlo,
el `script` `php` para la llamada es este:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
//$obj = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, true);

$url = 'http://192.168.xxxx:5001/ordenpedidos';


$resp = array('zona' => 7356 , 'id_tab_campania' => 289, 'impreso' => 1);
#   echo json_encode($resp);


$options = array(
'http' => array(
'method'  => 'POST',
'content' => json_encode($resp),
'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
           "Accept: application/json\r\n"
)
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context );
#$response = json_decode( $result );

print_r(json_decode($result));  
?>
```

le paso 3 parametros y el web service me devuelve un `json` .

### Edición:

Esto era lo que habia intentado hacer:

```
metadatos ={"zona":7356,"id_tab_campania":289,"impreso":1}
api_url_base = 'http://192.168.1.xxxx:5001/ordenpedidos'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.get(api_url_base, headers=headers,params=metadatos)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print( json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8')))
else:
    print( response.text)
```

y me arrojaba este error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

Comment: Hola Damian, si quieres usar la biblioteca estándar de Python mirate [urllib.requets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) o puedes usar el paquete [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) -> https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests.

Comment: Por otro lado, la pregunta tal como está posiblemente no sea bien recibida por pedir una traducción a otro lenguaje sin mostrar nada intentado hasta el momento, los votos negativos seguramente se deban a esto. Te aconsejo que mires los enlaces que te dejo arriba, elijas alguna opción e intentes implementarlo. Si te atascas edita la pregunta y agrega lo que has intentado, así se puede responder en base a un problema concreto sobre un código base. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola gracias, mañana público lo que intente hacer, porque lo tengo en la notebook al código en python. Pero me tiraba bad requests error 410 o 400 creo que era. Mañana subiré entonces la pregunta completa, y si. Lo traté de hacer con requests.get( dirección, params= ) lo único que recuerdo. Gracias !!

Comment: Umm 400 indica que la petición es incorrecta o corrupta y el servidor no puede procesarla, sería lo más común y debida a que durante el proceso de generar la petición con requests terminas construyendo una no válida por alguna razón (comúnmente al pasar el json). El 410 por otro lado indica que el archivo/página ya no está disponible, esto sería más raro. Actualizala cuando puedas y no te olvides de agregar el error exacto que te retorna el server a ver si podemos dar con la causa... Un saludo.

Comment: El ejemplo PHP que pones hace un "POST". Dices que tu intento de usar con `requests` usaba `.get()`. Esa puede ser la razón del "bad request", aunque lo lógico sería en este caso un error 405 Method not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dejo una forma simplificada (sin manejar los posibles excepciones `HTTPError` por ejemplo) de hacer la petición POST y obtener el JSON como diccionario Python, usando solo la biblioteca estándar con [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html):

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request


url = 'http://192.168.1.xxx:5001/ordenpedidos'
payload = {"zona": 7356, "id_tab_campania": 289, "impreso": 1}

enc_payload = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode()
request =  urllib.request.Request(url, data=enc_payload)

with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
    if response.code == 200:
        charset = response.info().get_content_charset("utf-8")
        resp_cont = response.read().decode(charset)
        json_resp = json.loads(resp_cont)
        print(json_resp)
```

El método se puede especificar con el argumento `method de` `urllib.request.Request`, pudiendo ser `"POST"` o `"GET"`, no obstante si el argumento`data` no es `None` se usará `POST` automáticamente.

Realmente no difiere mucho de requests, excepto porque con este último podemos usar el método [`.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content), en vez de usar el módulo `json` de la stdlib, para obtener el diccionario a partir del JSON de la respuesta, en cuyo caso además el encoding es autodetectado por requests.

La otra diferencia es la necesidad de parsear los datos de forma explícita a una cadena ascci usando *percent-encoded* para lo que hacemos uso de [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode).

Obviamente suele ser más complejo realizar las mismas operaciones con urllib que con requests, no en vano el lema de ésta última es *"HTTP para humanos"*...

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo marco como respuesta correcta por que además de responder la consulta, se hizo una muy buena explicación, saludos

Answer (score 4):

Gracias a los comentarios sugeridos pude resolverlo de esta manera, nose si será la correcta, pero la comparto porque de seguro existe una mejor,

```
import requests
import json
if __name__ =='__main__':
    url='http://192.168.1.xxx:5001/ordenpedidos'
    payload = {"zona":7356,"id_tab_campania":289,"impreso":1}
    response = requests.post(url,json=payload)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(response.content)
```

efectivamente el problema era el `get()` como bien me han indicado en los comentarios.

*pd: No la marcaré como respuesta por el momento, hasta ver si aparece alguna forma mas eficiente.*
Gracias